# Cron job is not working in centos 6.6

Tags: php, centos, cron

I have dedicated server having centos 6.6 and centos webpanel. Now I'm trying to set cron job from centos web panel. I had tried so many commands to run one php file each and every minute, but still cron job is not making my file run each minute. Further configuration: Kernel Version: 2.6.32-26-pve, Platform: i686, Distro Name: CentOS release 6.6 (Final), MySQL version: 5.1.73, PHP version: 5.4.27, Apache version: Apache/2.2.27.
Below is the list of all commands I had tried. Please help me with cron job. Thanks.

```
* * * * * public_html/run.php
* * * * * /public_html/run.php
* * * * * /bin/php -q /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * run.php
* * * * * /run.php
* * * * * /public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * ~user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name /public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name /run.php
* * * * * user_name run.php
* * * * * user_name /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * /bin/php -q /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name /bin/php -q /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * /usr/local/php -q /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * user_name /usr/local/php -q /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * /home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * home/user_name/public_html/run.php
* * * * * /usr/local/php -q home/user_name/public_html/run.php
```

I'm able to run this file from browser and it gives expected result also, but cron job is not able to run this file. Also I'm able to access this file in both ways, first using domain name like `www.example.com/run.php` and another method like `http://my_ip_address/~user/run.php`.

Comment: While this question does have something to do with programming, it might be more appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: please tell me what should I need to do?

Comment: I think there is some problem with command, not with server

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

exampledomain ="exampledomain.com"

php -q /home/exampledomain/public_html/filepath/filepath/result.php